# Android Studio Build Time with Gradle dependency vs Jar dependency

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I am working in a product in which we are using 4 external libraries. All of these libraries were being included through External Jars. Build time with the Jar dependencies were about 10 minutes. I changed Jar dependencies with the Gradle dependencies and then build time came to 3.5 minutes.

Dependencies before (10 minutes Build time)

```
compile fileTree(dir: '../../dml/lib', include: ['handlebars-proto-4.0.6.jar'])
compile fileTree(dir: '../../dml/lib', include: ['itextpdf-5.5.11.jar'])
compile fileTree(dir: '../../dml/lib', include: ['xmlworker-5.5.11.jar'])
compile fileTree(include: ['joda-time-2.4.jar'], dir: '../../stdlib_java/lib')
```

I changed with Gradle Dependencies (3 Minutes 40 Seconds Build Time)

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.6'
compile 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.11'
compile group: 'com.github.jknack', name: 'handlebars', version: '4.0.6'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
```

Will you please clear my confusion whats going on inside ?

Comment: Is it also true for only one of your .jar dependency ? And in both cases  (local and distant) do you use a full rebuild gradle command ?

Comment: i am trying rebuild while checking the time. All jars are available locally in lib folder.