# Will converting modules to external gradle dependencies improve build time?

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have an android app in which I have 5 modules say ModuleA, ModuleB, ..., ModuleE. The build time of the app is around 7~8 minutes. Will converting each module to an external gradle dependency help improve the build time? I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690228/android-studio-build-time-with-gradle-dependency-vs-jar-dependency) and it says that the build time was reduced significantly. How does this reduce the build time? Can someone explain how Gradle dependencies tend to build faster than using separate modules?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many things. Multiple modules help to improve build time, but that doesn't mean creating many modules, build time will be faster.

The build time will be the same on the first build and clean rebuild. But at other times, Gradle will only build the module where the change occurred. It will not build the modules that haven't changed. There you save some build time by creating modules. So planning the modules is an important factor for this.

Comment: That much I understand. What I don't get is that will converting these modules to gradle dependencies improve the build time?

Comment: The concept is also the same in this case. Because the modules are also added as dependencies.

Comment: If you are concerned about improving the build time, check this article. https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-decrease-your-gradle-build-time-by-65-310b572b0c43